# Ucase equivalent in Hibernate/Projections?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have been searching a lot to find a hibernate/projection code(/function) equivalent for Ucase/Lcase function in simple SQL. Does such thing exist actually? Before delaying any further I will explain my situation.

I have two Tables(One to One) - StudentBean and AddressBean. I'm using a simple object(of Studentbean) embedding mechanism inside AddressBean to keep track of their relationship. I'm using the following method inside my AddressBean Manager class to get whole record (joined from 2 tables) from DB.

```
public List getAllDetails()
    {
        Criteria c = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(AddressBean.class);
        c.createAlias("studid", "student");
        c.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.property((String)"student.studid"), "studid")
            .add(Projections.property((String)"student.rollno"), "rollno")
            .add(Projections.property((String)"student.name"), "name")    
            .add(Projections.property((String)"student.phone"), "phone")
            .add(Projections.property((String)"address"), "address")
            .add(Projections.property((String)"place"), "place")
            .add(Projections.property((String)"city"), "city"));
            c.addOrder(Order.asc("city"));
        c.setResultTransformer((ResultTransformer)Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
        return c.list();
    }
```

The returned list is sorted properly based on 'city' column value. Now my requirement is to convert city column values to pure "UPPERCASE",just like we simply convert as **"SELECT UCASE(City) AS Customer, City
FROM Customers;"** in **Simple SQL**.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Column(name = "City")
@ColumnTransformer(read = "UPPER(City)")
private String city;
```

Change your entity class's `city` property like mentioned above and try...